# How to get the contract binary using web3.py?

Tags: contract-deployment, contract-invocation, web3.py

I am using web3.py and I want to get the binary (not the ABI) of a smart contract, given its address. Is it possible? If yes, how? If it isn't possible using web3.py, is there an alternative Python approach that I can use to get the binary of the smart contract?

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by using the following method: **web3.eth.get_code('0x6C8f2A135f6ed072DE4503Bd7C4999a1a17F824B')**

Ref: https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.get_code

Answer (score 0):

You need an API-key I am using Infura. Click the link and create an account. Their free tier covers 100000 API-calls per day so if you do not exceed this you are fine.
https://app.infura.io

```
from web3 import Web3

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/<you_own_infura_key>'))

bytecode = w3.eth.getCode(<your_address>)
```

If the it complains on checksum for the addres you provided use:

```
address2 = Web3.toChecksumAddress(addr)
```

Also if the format the bytecode is in is not pleasing (containing a lot of \x you can use the following function:

```
bytecode = w3.toHex(ugly_bytecode)
```